# Recursive & dynamic programming algorithm to find shortest path (length and actual path) from an arbitrary node to another

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was hoping for some help / direction on the following question, on which I am struggling. 
If you have any suggestions in re-wording the question, just leave a comment and I'll go ahead and change it.

Take a weighted directed acyclic graph.

(a) Recursive algorithm that finds shortest path from node x to node t (algorithm should try all outgoing edges and determine which to proceed on).

```
I was thinking something along the lines of breadth first search?
Maybe, another way, a recursive form of dijkstras? However, I'm having 
difficulty thinking of a recursive way to do this.
```

(b) Make an iterative dynamic programming version of the recursive algorithm and indicate how you find the actual path (rather than just the length of the path).

```
The difference here would obviously be that it is iterative. I'm also  
 guessing we would have to keep track of the length of the path / the 
 path itself (the nodes) in an array, and refer to it as we iterate.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `w(i,j)` be the weight of the edge between `i` to `j`, for any given edge `(i,j)`.

The recursive relation that can find the shortest path can be denoted as:

```
D(u,u) = 0
D(u,v) = min{ D(u,i) + w(i,v) | for each node i such that the edge (i,v) exists }
```

The shortest path is then denoted by `D(x,t)`.

Note that if there is a negative cycle - the algorithm will be stuck in an infinite loop (since `D(u,i) = -infinity` for this cycle), so for correctness of it, we have to assume no such cycle exists.

An iterative Dynamic Programming implementation to this relation is basically the [Bellman-Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you go a little more in-depth as to how exactly this works?

Comment: If there is a path from A to C such that there are two edges on that path that together weight 4, and one path from A to C such that its weight is 8. How will this algorithm decide to take the 2 edges of weight 4 instead of the 1 edge of weight 8?

Comment: @RonaldDonald This is what the `min{}` is for. It is choosing the path with minimal cost.

Comment: Yea, I went through it and I finally understand.

Comment: I've been trying to think about how to transform this into the dynamic programming solution. Didn't quite see the connection with the Bellman-Ford algorithm

Comment: @RonaldDonald Bellman-Ford finds at the i'th iteration the shortest path of length at most `i`, by following this recursive formula